understanding double balances mixer current polarity
There is a manual in the link explaining the double balanced mixer. 
They say that when we look from the perspective of the RF signal on the right, 
We have a GND on the left side as presented in the photo. 
Two questions: 
1.LO signal is also could be high frequency why the coils on the left are effective shorts? 
2.Why when RF amplitude rises on the right side we have a current as in the red arrow,
Its not very intuitive because the current is from high to low voltage potential.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=junuEwmQVQ8



1.LO signal is also could be high frequency why the coils on the left are effective shorts?

That three-coil transformer has identical voltages across all three coils. And current through diodes and through two of those windings is pretty much identical...we consider local oscillator current to vastly dominate any RF current that is superimposed.
When local oscillator signal reaches a +ve peak, those two diodes are conducting hard which makes their equivalent "ON" resistance equal, and rather small. Thus diode junction is forced equal to the centre-tap point of the transformer (which is ground).
It is incorrect to think of those two coils "shorted". Each coil has identical voltage across it, forced by the forward voltage of the two diodes (0.7V). Here's a snapshot of the voltage distribution at the moment when L.O. reached its +ve peak:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
 Even L1 has 0.7V across it. VL.O. must be higher than 0.7V, else the diodes don't conduct enough to force their junction to GND. Diode current is set by (VL.O. - 0.7)/R1. For this example, you'd want VL.O. peak-to-peak amplitude somewhat greater than 2V.

The other two diodes (on the right) reach this same conducting condition when VL.O. swings to its negative peak.
This is a simplification, assuming local oscillator current greatly dominates R.F. input current. More accurately, one of those diodes sees a bit more current than the other due to I.F. current. The effect is that the diode junction has a small impedance to ground, which appears in series with I.F. output.
The two banks of diode pairs alternately conduct, driven by local oscillator. If you think of those diodes as switches, alternately open-circuit then short circuit, the effect is like this:

simulate this circuit
 As a matter of fact, MOSfet SPDT switch makes an excellent mixer.

Hello glen_geek,So if the RF part of the LO signal makes a current on the coil that cancel each other leaving only the DC part, then also the right side of the "RF PORT" also create a current on the coils that cancel each other . The structure of the coils is the same.So why on the left side we have cancelation of rf currents while on the right side we dont have cancelation of RF currents?

Correct. Made a change...it is I.F. output that causes imbalance. When diodes are not matched, transformer windings are not matched, then some of the large L.O. signal leaks back into R.F. port. Any I.F. output signal similarly causes a bit of L.O. to appear at the R.F. port.

Hello glen_geek,I have built a basic  diode ring mixer in LTspice.I dont understant why the RF signal on the right side flippes the RF signal?
Is there a way I could see why the current switched direction on the load?
I dont know how to add ASC simulation files and photos in the comments,so I added photos I upladed in the links.
https://ibb.co/74wnZqL
https://ibb.co/Qvz7yZc
https://ibb.co/wzKW6mY

Is this mixer meant to be an AM modulator?. If so, the baseband signal (0.4V, 10kHz) should be applied between transformer centre-taps. And the RF signal (1V, 100kHz) should be applied at the left (or right). For AM, the TRANSient spec for the baseband signal should add a DC offset, something like this: SINE(0.2 0.2 10k) . I think 0.4V for baseband amplitude is a bit too much, and 1V for RF signal is a bit too feeble. Without DC offset, you have DSB with suppressed carrier.

Hello glen_geek,I am just using this circuit purely to understand the current situation for properly functioning double balanced mixer.Why did you say that RF of 1V is too weak?
Thanks.

Most folks run these DBMs so that diode current is dominated by the local oscillator, with the other port's current much weaker in comparison. In this way, mixer throughput gain is highest, like -5 dB. You can even drive the local oscillator port with a square wave, perhaps swinging from +1V to -1V. Many mixer diodes might handle peak local oscillator current of 10 mA. You're using 1n4148 diodes rather than schottky diodes, so L.O. might be near 3V pk-pk feeding that 50 ohm resistor.


The magnetic fields caused by the R.F. signal current in the leftmost transformer cancel each other because the upper half of the center tapped coil magnetizes the core to the opposite direction than the lower half of the coil.

Most of the time the LO signal wins in diodes what's coming from the RF input. The conduction state of the diodes is most of the time determined by the LO signal. The voltage of the LO signal is so much higher than the voltage of the RF signal. The explanation in the video IS ok including the higher potential terminal of a signal source outputs the current or actually that component of the total current which belongs to the signal.



Hello ,I have built a basic  diode ring mixer in LTspice.I dont understant why the RF signal on the right side flippes the RF signal?
Is there a way I could see why the current switched direction on the load?
I dont know how to add ASC simulation files and photos in the comments,so I added photos I upladed in the links.
https://ibb.co/74wnZqL
https://ibb.co/Qvz7yZc
https://ibb.co/wzKW6mY

@user451625 No idea what you are trying!! You have placed source V2 where I expect to see the load for the mixing result  and you have R3 in the place where I would have the R.F. source. At least insert some explanation how the new linked image is related with the original double balanced mixer article (expect by having as many diodes and coils). Is this perhaps an attempt to to mix the signal frequency upwards?
